# Sudo requiring password

Tags: rhel, sudo

On a RHEL server I would like to let a user run a command as root without a password:

```
# uname -a
Linux foo.com 2.6.32-220.38.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 15 08:34:56 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# cat /etc/issue
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
Kernel \r on an \m

# visudo
User_Alias FOOEMPLOYEES = someuser
Cmnd_Alias FOOCOMMANDS = /root/bin/fix-permissions
FOOEMPLOYEES   ALL = NOPASSWD: FOOCOMMANDS
```

For some reason, the system is still asking the user for his password:

```
$ alias
alias fix-permissions='/root/bin/fix-permissions'

$ fix-permissions 
-bash: /root/bin/fix-permissions: Permission denied

$ sudo fix-permissions 
[sudo] password for someuser:
```

**Why might the `sudo` configuration not work?** Did I configure it wrong? I copied the configuration from [this guide](http://www.ducea.com/2006/05/19/linux-tips-the-proper-way-to-allow-regular-users-to-run-commands-as-root/).

Comment: Do the command start without sudo with full path `/root/bin/fix-permissions`? And the last string shoul be ` FOOEMPLOYEES   ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: FOOCOMMANDS`

Comment: From the `man sudoers` > The basic structure of a user specification is “who where = (as_whom) what”

Comment: Thank you! I've updated the visudo line to `FOOEMPLOYEES ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: FOOCOMMANDS`. Running `/root/bin/fix-permissions` still comments that permission is denied, but running `sudo /root/bin/fix-permissions` actually works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last string should be

```
FOOEMPLOYEES ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: FOOCOMMANDS
```

From the `man sudoers`

> The basic structure of a user specification is “who where = (as_whom)
>   what”